# PRAW returning a 404 HTTP exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, praw

I've never had trouble with my code before and this error occurs when attempting to read the inbox.

Traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run1.py", line 711, in <module>
    run_bot(r, comments_replied_to)
  File "run1.py", line 697, in run_bot
    readinbox()
  File "run1.py", line 58, in readinbox
    mods = r.subreddit(message.body).moderator()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/praw/models/reddit/subreddit.py", line 1723, in __call__
    return self.subreddit._reddit.get(url, params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 408, in get
    data = self.request('GET', path, params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 534, in request
params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 185, in request
params=params, url=url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 130, in _request_with_retries
    raise self.STATUS_EXCEPTIONS[response.status_code](response)
prawcore.exceptions.NotFound: received 404 HTTP response
```

Is PRAW/Reddit having issues?

Comment: Can you please provide a MWE?

Comment: Can you please make an edit to add your source code?

Comment: Where is your code?